# Como solucionar o erro: Method getClientOrinalExtension does not exist, no upload de imagem com o laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Mais uma vez preciso muito da vossa ajuda. Está me dando o seguinte erro ao fazer o upload de imagem no laravel 5.4:

> `Method getClientOrinalExtension does not exist.`

A seguir vai o meu controller e a view:

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Posts;
//use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public  function index()
    {
        //
    }


    public  function create()
    {
        if(Input::file('imagem'))
        {
            $imagem = Input::file('imagem');
            $extensao = $imagem->getClientOrinalExtension();

            if($extensao != 'jpg' && $extensao != 'png')
            {
                return back()->with('Erro','Erro: Este arquivo não é uma imagem JPG ou PNG');
            }
        }
        $post = new Posts();
        $post->titulo = Input::get('titulo');
        $post->conteudo = Input::get('conteudo');
        $post->imagem ="";
        $post->save();

        if(Input::file('imagem'))
        {
            File::move($imagem,public_path().'/imagem-post/post-id_'.$post->id.'.'.$extensao);
            $post->imagem = public_path().'/imagem-post/post-id_'.$post->id.'.'.$extensao;
            $post->save();
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@extends('main')
@section('content')
    <form action="{{ url('criar-post') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}

        @if(session('erro'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{session('erro')}}
            </div>
        @endif

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="titulo">Título</label>
            <input name="titulo" type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo" placeholder="Título">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="conteudo">Conteúdo</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="conteudo" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="imagem">Imagem</label>
            <input type="file" id="imagem" name="imagem">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na própria mensagem de erro já descobre o problema:

```
Method getClientOrinalExtension does not exist.
```

realmente não existe esse método, porque o seu nome está ***errado***, o correto é:

```
Input::file('imagem')->getClientOriginalExtension()
```

Comment: aquele erro sumiu, está gravando os outros dados no banco, mas não está gravando o caminho da imagem. Pelo que notei, nem está fazendo o upload da imagem, porque a pasta de destino está vazia, e está dando o seguinte erro: rename(jpg,C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema53\public/imagem-post/post-id_.jpg): O sistema n�o conseguiu localizar o ficheiro especificado. (code: 2)

Comment: Tem que dar permissão na pasta temp acho que está `c:\windows\temp` @DanieldosSantos

Comment: Desculpa @VirgilioNovic, o que é isso "dar permissão"? Como faria isso?